# How do I concatenate two arrays of different datatypes in BigQuery?

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

When I try to concatenate two arrays of same datatype it works perfectly fine.

An example is shown below

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  table1 AS (
  SELECT 'a' id UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c'
  ),
  table2 AS (
  SELECT 'a' id, [1,2,3,4,5] array_1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', [1,2,3,4,5] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', [1,2,3,4,5]
  ),
  table3 AS (
  SELECT 'a' id, [10,20,30,40,50] array_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', [10,20,30,40,50] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', []
  ),
  joined_table as (
  select table1.id,
  table2.array_1,
  table3.array_2
  from 
    table1
  JOIN table2
  USING(id)
  JOIN table3
  using(id)
  )
SELECT
  joined_table.*,
  ARRAY_CONCAT(IFNULL(joined_table.array_1,[]), IFNULL(joined_table.array_2,[])) as concatanated_arrays
  FROM joined_table
```

But when I try to do the concatenation, but the arrays are of different datatype, like the example query below:

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  table1 AS (
  SELECT 'a' id UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c'
  ),
  table2 AS (
  SELECT 'a' id, [1,2,3,4,5] array_1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', [1,2,3,4,5] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', [1,2,3,4,5]
  ),
  table3 AS (
  SELECT 'a' id, ['10','20','30','40','50'] array_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', ['10','20','30','40','50'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', []
  ),
  joined_table as (
  select table1.id,
  table2.array_1,
  table3.array_2
  from 
    table1
  JOIN table2
  USING(id)
  JOIN table3
  using(id)
  )
SELECT
  joined_table.*,
  ARRAY_CONCAT(IFNULL(joined_table.array_1,[]), IFNULL(joined_table.array_2,[])) as concatanated_arrays
  FROM joined_table
```

my query does not run and show an error like this:

`Error: No matching signature for function ARRAY_CONCAT for argument types: ARRAY<INT64>, ARRAY<STRING>. Supported signature: ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY, [ARRAY, ...]) at [31:3]`

How do I concatenate these two arrays of different type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays with different datatypes can not be concatenated in BigQuery. You need the datatypes to be the same when concatenating arrays.

One way to solve the problem at hand would be to convert the integer arrays into string and then concatenating them to get the combined array.

The following query can be used in BigQuery standard-sql to demonstrate one such example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  table1 AS (
  SELECT 'a' id UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c'
  ),
  table2 AS (
  SELECT 'a' id, [1,2,3,4,5] array_1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', [1,2,3,4,5] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', [1,2,3,4,5]
  ),
  table3 AS (
  SELECT 'a' id, ['10','20','30','40','50'] array_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', ['10','20','30','40','50'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', []
  ),
  joined_table as (
  select table1.id,
  table2.array_1,
  table3.array_2
  from 
    table1
  JOIN table2
  USING(id)
  JOIN table3
  using(id)
  )
SELECT
  joined_table.*,
  ARRAY_CONCAT(IFNULL(ARRAY(SELECT CAST(value as string) FROM UNNEST(joined_table.array_1) value),[]), IFNULL(joined_table.array_2,[])) as concatanated_arrays
  FROM joined_table
```

But as a result the final `concatenated_arrays` become a repeated string field.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative (lighter) version - BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT CAST(val AS STRING) FROM t.array_1 val UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM t.array_2
  ) concatanated_arrays
FROM joined_table t
```

If to apply to sample data in question - produces expected result